# Django: How to do Aggregate (GroupBy ID) & Latest timestamp?

Tags: django

I have a table like this:

```
ID    | Time Stamp
1     | 2012-07-28 18:57:48.160912+01 
1     | 2012-07-28 20:57:43.063327+01
2     | 2012-07-28 21:17:16.016665+01
```

I would like to see the latest entry of each id.

If I did this, I would get only one object with the very latest entry:

```
open_deals = all_deals.latest('time_stamp'))

-->     2    | 2012-07-28 21:17:16.016665+01
```

But I would like to get

```
-->    1     | 2012-07-28 20:57:43.063327+01
       2     | 2012-07-28 21:17:16.016665+01
```

I need somehow to aggregate or Groupby the ID. But there is no function for that in the documentation.

Any tips? Thank you

**Update:**

I have tried the solution below:

```
result_list = [deal.dealchangelog_set.latest('time_stamp') for deal in open_deals]
        result_set = set()
        for item in result_list:
            result_set.add(item.pk)
        return open_deals.filter(pk__in = result_set)
```

[image]

Unfortunatelly as you can see the list still contains three objects instead of two. :-(

Here are my models (beware I am not using the deal_id as pk) The pk is still as integers.
In my case, I need to get the latest of the deal_id, which isn't unique. (For sake of simplicity I had shown previously the uuid in here as integer)

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    deal_id             = UUIDField()
    status              = models.ForeignKey(DealStatus, verbose_name=_(u"Deal Status"), null=True, blank=True)    
    contact             = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    deal_type           = models.ForeignKey(DealType)    

class DealChangeLog(models.Model):
    deal                = models.ForeignKey(Deal)
    time_stamp          = CreationDateTimeField()
```

**Update 2:**

```
def get_open_deals(call):
        all_deals = Deal.objects.filter(contact=call.contact)            
        closed_deals = all_deals.filter(status__in=[5, 6])
        closed_deal_list = []
        if closed_deals:
            for item in closed_deals:
                closed_deal_list.append(item.deal_id)
        open_deals = all_deals.exclude(deal_id__in=closed_deal_list)        
        result_list = [deal.dealchangelog_set.latest('time_stamp') for deal in open_deals]
        result_set = set()
        for item in result_list:
            result_set.add(item.pk)
        return open_deals.filter(pk__in = result_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not context aware but I would probably break up the model like this:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    # maybe signal changes etcetera... 

class DealChangeLog(models.Model):
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deal)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

Then you could achieve your result by list comprehension:

```
results = [deal.dealchangelog_set.latest('date') for deal in Deal.objects.all()]
```

To get the results as a queryset you can do:

```
Deal.objects.filter(id__in=[result.deal.id for result in results])
```

But if you can work with the results as a list I don't see much point for the extra queries

Comment: ,thanks for the solution. I have tried it. But I need the result as a QuerySet instead of a list. Is that possible? `formset = deal_formset(queryset=get_latest_deals())`

Comment: Ah no worries, I have figured out how to make a queryset out of it, the solution still doesn't work though. I have posted more information. Many thanks

Comment: I have added the results as a queryset, but is there a reason you can't work with a list?

Comment: Oh I see. Please ignore my comment regarding the queryset, as I have solved it. However your actual List still contains three items instead of two. Please have a look at the screenshot above. `Open_deals` is the original queryset that contains all three items. `result_list` is literally the list you have suggested and yet it contains all three entries, instead of two.

Comment: What actually represents open_deals?

Comment: `open_deals` is also a queryset. Please see the new updated question with the full content.

Comment: Did you make UUIDField() the primary key?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14590/discussion-between-kave-and-argskwargs)